# The \list command

Tags: lists

Consider the following code listing from p. 82 of [the TikZ & PGF manual for version 3.0.1a](http://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf):

[image: A code listing from the TikZ & PGF manual]

```
\def\lecture#1#2#3#4#5#6{
  \node [annotation, #3, scale=0.65, text width=4cm, inner sep=2mm] at (#4) {
    Lecture #1: \textcolor{orange}{\textbf{#2}}
    \list{--}{\topsep=2pt\itemsep=0pt\parsep=0pt
              \parskip=0pt\labelwidth=8pt\leftmargin=8pt
              \itemindent=0pt\labelsep=2pt}
    #5
    \endlist
  };
}
```

The listing uses a pair of commands: `\list` and `\endlist`. The `\list` command takes two arguments: `{--}` and `{\topset...=2pt}`.

The `\list` command is not listed in the TikZ manual's index, nor in the indices of Knuth's *The TeX Book* or Lamport's *LaTeX*.

To which system/package does this command belong?
What is its syntax?
What are its semantics?

Comment: `\list` and `\endlist` are the commands corresponding to the start and end of the `list` environment.

Comment: @karlkoeller: Thanks. Can you speculate why the TikZ manual avoided using the `list` environment in the above code listing?

Comment: See also `texdoc source2e`, search for `\def\list`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: A search for `\def\list` in [texdoc](http://texdoc.net/) resulted in no matches.

Comment: No, but search for `source2e`, open the PDF, and search in the PDF. (`texdoc` is a command line tool, so you can open a terminal/command prompt on your computer, and type `texdoc source2e` to get the same PDF, that was what I meant.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: I see. Thanks. However a search for `\def\list` in the PDF file opened by running `texdoc source2e` at the terminal yielded no results either.

Comment: Well, it's there. I don't know which version you have, but look in the table of contents for "Lists, and related environments", it's in that chapter. (Chapter 54, page 286 on my system, TeX Live 2016.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: I use TeX Live 2017. The expression `\def\list` doesn't seem to be there, but `\list` and `\endlist` are discussed in chapter 55 *List, and related environments* starting on p. 283. At any rate, thanks. I wasn't aware of the existence of `texdoc`.

Comment: @EvanAad In `texdoc source2e` included with TeX Live 2017, look for `\def\list` at the bottom of page 290, numbered line 34 — the chapter this occurs in is "File A: ltlists.dtx" aka "Lists, and related environments". (You can find this by looking in the index under L for `\list`, and following the underlined index entry, which stands for where it's defined.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code above is not particularly instructive for beginners and should be accompanied by explicatory notes.

It takes advantage of two facts:

1. the code in the main argument to `\node` is executed in a `\parbox`, due to setting of `text width`, which forms a (TeX) group;
2. code such as `\begin{env}...\end{env}` is essentially equivalent to

   ```
   \begingroup
   <some bookkeeping>
   \env
   ...
   \endenv
   <some bookkeeping>
   \endgroup
   ```

The bookkeeping is, in this case, irrelevant, because the whole construction is performed in the group provided by `\parbox`.

Never use `\list...\endlist` in the wild, because not doing the bookkeeping will almost certainly have adverse effects.

The code should better be, from a teacher’s point of view,

```
\newcommand{\lecture}[6]{%
  \node [annotation, #3, scale=0.65, text width=4cm, inner sep=2mm] at (#4) {
    Lecture #1: \textcolor{orange}{\textbf{#2}}
    \begin{list}{--}{%
      \setlength{\topsep}{2pt}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
      \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
      \setlength{\labelwidth}{8pt}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{8pt}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{0pt}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{2pt}%
    }%
    #5
    \end{list}
  };
}
```

Optimizations such as those require experience and actually don't gain much.

Better yet, one could do

```
\newenvironment{lecturelist}
 {\begin{list}{--}{%
    \setlength{\topsep}{2pt}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{8pt}%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{8pt}%
    \setlength{\itemindent}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\labelsep}{2pt}%
  }%
  {\end{list}}
```

and then

```
\newcommand{\lecture}[6]{%
  \node [annotation, #3, scale=0.65, text width=4cm, inner sep=2mm] at (#4) {
    Lecture #1: \textcolor{orange}{\textbf{#2}}
    \begin{lecturelist}
    #5
    \end{lecturelist}
  };
}
```

In the code for `lecturelist` it would be good to change `\begin{list}` and `\end{list}` with `\list` and `\endlist` respectively: the bookkeeping will be taken care of by `\begin{lecturelist}` and `\end{lecturelist}`, so it doesn't need to be done in the inner part. It would also give better error messages in case one doesn't properly close the `lecturelist` package.

Comment: Thanks. Can you speculate why the TikZ manual avoided using the list environment in the above code listing? Is it possible to replace the `\list...\endlist` in the manual's code listing by `\begin{list}...\end{list}` with no (ill) effect?

Comment: @EvanAad I'd say that `\begin{list}...\end{list}` *ought to* be used, along with `\newcommand{\lecture}[6]{...}`.

Comment: @EvanAad I added some more comments

Comment: Thanks. This is much clearer, except for the last sentence, where you seem to contradict your former exhortation not to use `\list` and `\endlist`.

Comment: @EvanAad No contradiction! That's not using `\list` and `\endlist` *in the wild*, but in the definition of a new environment: the bookkeeping is taken care of by the `lecturelist` outer environment.

Comment: I see. But why would it be better in this situation to prefer `\list` and `\endlist` to `\begin{list}` and \end{list}`?