# What is the difference of using \list vs. \begin{list} and \endlist vs. \end{list}

Tags: environments, lists

When creating environments based on `list` I have seen two implementations:

```
\documentclass{report} 

\newenvironment{examplea}{%
\begin{list}{}{% stuff here
}}
{\end{list}}

\newenvironment{exampleb}{%
\list{}{% stuff here
}}
{\endlist}

\begin{document}

\begin{examplea}
\item bla
\end{examplea}

\begin{exampleb}
\item bla
\end{exampleb}
 
\end{document}
```

They both seem to be behaving the same way. In comments [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/375531/100817) it is recommended not to use `\list` and `\endlist` *in the wild* ... but that leaves unanswered the question about their difference.

What is the difference in using `\list`  vs.  `\begin{list}` and `\endlist` vs. `\end{list}`?
Are there contexts where I should *not* use `\begin{list}` and `\end{list}`, for instance?

Comment: Mostly, `\begin` sets `\@currenvir` and `\end` checks it; hence the error message "\begin{list} was ended by \end{document}" (for example).  There was a time I worried about nesting environments before I realized that `\@currenvir` was being stored locally in nested groups.

Comment: @user202729  It does :) ... only now I'm wondering why anyone would ever use the `begin` ... `end` format?

Comment: `\begin` and `\end` have changed in the LaTeX kernel since Martin Scharrer wrote [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14684/73317). If you don't call them for the inner environment, its `\BeforeBeginEnvironment`, `\AtBeginEnvironment`, `\AtEndEnvironment`
and `\AfterEndEnvironment` hooks won't be run! AFAIK, the hooks were added in 2020; see `texdoc lthooks`.